# Is there a closed form for this infinite sum of Hermite polynomials?

Tags: number-theory, closed-form, hermite-polynomials

**Context:**

I've derived these two series that both converge to the same value:

\begin{align}
f:&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\pi n^2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(16)^{-k}\,H_{4k}\,(n\,\sqrt{2\pi})}{(2k+1)!} =\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac74 \\
\\
g:&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{\pi n^2} \left(\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{E}_{\frac32}\left(\pi\, n^2\right)-\mathrm{E}_{\frac32}\left(2\pi\, n^2\right) \right)=\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac74
\end{align}

where $\mathrm{E}_a(b)$ is the [generalized Exponential Integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19) .

It is nice to see how the exponentials, with either a negative or a positive power, both get 'tamed' towards the same value.

**Question:**

Does a closed form expression also exist for the infinite sum of Hermite polynomials?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(16)^{-k}\,H_{4k}\,(n\,\sqrt{2\pi})}{(2k+1)!}$$

Checked the 15 summation formulae on [this page](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/HermiteH/23/02/), however they all seem to rely on the requirement that the factorial and the first parameter of $H$ have the same structure. In my case these are different, hence I expect some additional trick is required.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this sum can be transformed into an inverse [Hermite transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_transform)? Exchanging integral and sum gives [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5B%28e%5E%28-t%5E2%29+sinh%28%28t+-+i+x%29%5E2%29%29%2F%28sqrt%28π%29+%28t+-+i+x%29%5E2%29%2C%7Bt%2C-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D)

Comment: @https://math.stackexchange.com/users/905886/tyma-gaidash That looks like a nice approach. I don't have access to the Wolfram Pro environment and ran into a time-out when evaluating the integral. Did the integral get simplified any further by Mathematica?

Comment: The comment was just to show the integral representation as I do not have Mathematica

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. I will try it on my Raspberry Pi that has a free version of Mathematica!